# css lost in print div by jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div to print, but somehow borders do not show in print window, so I tried to set border again just before print. I can change border color in console but it disappear in print. 
here is my print function:

```
function printDiv(tableId) {
        //I change css here again see code 2
        var divToPrint = document.getElementById(tableId);
        newWin = window.open("");
        newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
        newWin.print();
        newWin.close();
        dailyPatients()

    }
```

Here is the code 2 that work in console.

```
//can remove a column
$("#uselectedPatients th:last-child, #uselectedPatients td:last-child").remove();
//this only change border around the table
$("#uselectedPatients").css("border", "solid #eee 1px")
//this works in console but not in print window
$("#uselectedPatients >tbody>tr>td").css("border-color", "black")
```

Comment: Try using outline instead of border in print media query. Hope it will work.

Comment: It has same effect, i want to change color of all borders including cells. Outline only change color of table perimeter

Comment: Try using above default css into the @media print query.